# use of Sys::SigAction::timeout_call unsafe?

Tags: perl, signals, setjmp

I've just read Leon Timmermans' article [What you should know about signal based timeouts](http://blogs.perl.org/users/leon_timmermans/2012/01/what-you-should-know-about-signal-based-timeouts.html) and I was wondering how it/if it applies to the use of `Sys::SigAction::timeout_call()`.

1) First of all, it seems that `timeout_call()` uses `longjmp` and unsafe signals, and therefore   [CERT Secure Coding rule SIG32-C](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/SIG32-C.+Do+not+call+longjmp%28%29+from+inside+a+signal+handler) is applicable.

2) Is `timeout_call` safe to use if the code being monitored for timeouts only contains pure-perl code (i.e. no calls to XS modules)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) `timeout_call()` uses almost the exact same idiom to wrap a system call in an `eval/alarm` block as Leon's example:

```
my $ALARM_EXCEPTION = "alarm clock restart";
my $h;
eval {
    $h = set_sig_handler('ALRM', sub { die $ALARM_EXCEPTION }, { });
    alarm 10;
    flock $fh, 2 or die "cannot flock: $!";
    alarm 0;
};
alarm 0;
$SIG{ALRM} = $h;
if ($@ && $@ !~ quotemeta($ALARM_EXCEPTION)) { die }
```

So if `set_sig_handler` disables/overrides safe signal handling, then `timeout_call` will, too.

2) Pure Perl can still have plenty of interaction with the operating system, and how each system call responds to signals can vary widely between platforms. So in general the answer is no.