# WWW::Mechanize::Timed https timeout does not work

Tags: perl, https, timeout, try-catch, www-mechanize

So I've researched to the ends of the internet (at least I think so) about this issue. I'm trying to set an `alarm` timeout of 60 seconds for a `get()` but it does not get caught and will run past 60 seconds, also any time the default timeout (180 sec) is reached for the www::mechanized::timed constructor, I get the error below:

Use of uninitialized value in addition (+) at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/WWW/Mechanize/Timed.pm line 52.

code:

```
use WWW::Mechanize::Timed;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use Try::Tiny;

my $ua = WWW::Mechanize::Timed->new(
autocheck => 0#turning off autocheck becuase any get errors will be fatal need to check ourselves
);

my $cookies = HTTP::Cookies->new(
autosave => 1
);

$ua->cookie_jar($cookies);

$ua->agent_alias("Windows IE 6");

try{
local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" };
alarm 60;
$ua->get('https://secure.site.com'); #secure site that timed out
alarm 0;
} catch {
die $_ unless $_ eq "alarm\n";
print "page timed out after 60 seconds!\n";
exit;
};

my $total_time = sprintf '%.3f', ($ua->client_elapsed_time);

unless($ua->success){
print "Error: " . $ua->status;
exit;
}
...
```

I've gone over these questions to figure out how to get alarm to work without writing my own timeout function.

[Perl Mechanize timeout not working with https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209915/perl-mechanize-timeout-not-working-with-https)
and
[Ways to do timeouts in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423288/ways-to-do-timeouts-in-perl)

So far I see recommendations for using LWPx::ParanoidAgent, not sure if I understand the "Use LWPx::ParanoidAgent and mix it into Mech" part

[Possible to use timeout in WWW::Mechanize on https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330610/possible-to-use-timeout-in-wwwmechanize-on-https)

or patching LWP::UserAgent with

http://search.cpan.org/~sharyanto/LWP-UserAgent-Patch-HTTPSHardTimeout-0.04/lib/LWP/UserAgent/Patch/HTTPSHardTimeout.pm

Any thoughts on how to get the timeout to work with alarm?

Thanks!

Comment: [Bug #57748](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=57748) could cause this. I'd simply use Sys::SigAction with Time::HiRes for the timeout and the elapsed time.

Comment: Awesome thanks for pointing this bug out.  After looking into Sys::Sig Action some more (didnt fully understand it the first time i came across it) I was able to implement it without having to use Time::HiRes for elapsed time (still able to use timers in WWW::Mechanize::Timed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below helped to set an alarm for each `get()`, Seems much easier than try-catch with sig `alarm` unless i'm missing something?

```
use Sys::SigAction qw(timeout_call);

if ( timeout_call( 60 ,sub { $ua->get('https://secured.site.com'); } ))
   {
print "ALARM page timed out after 60 seconds!\n" ;
exit;
}
```

Pretty much the same answer as this question but with actual code [Ways to do timeouts in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423288/ways-to-do-timeouts-in-perl)

text from http://metacpan.org/pod/Sys::SigAction

> timeout_call()
>
> `$timeout ,$coderef`
>
> Given a code reference, and a timeout value (in
>   seconds), timeout() will (in an eval) setup a signal handler for
>   SIGALRM (which will die), set an alarm clock, and execute the code
>   reference. $time (seconds) may be expressed as a floating point
>   number.
>
> If Time::HiRes is present and useable, timeout_call() can be used with
>   a timer resolution of 0.000001 seconds. If Time:HiRes is not available
>   then factional second values less than 1.0 are tranparently converted
>   to 1.
>
> If the alarm goes off the code will be interrupted. The alarm is
>   canceled if the code returns before the alarm is fired. The routine
>   returns true if the code being executed timed out. (was interrupted).
>   Exceptions thrown by the code executed are propagated out.
>
> The original signal handler is restored, prior to returning to the
>   caller.
>
> If HiRes is not loadable, Sys::SigAction will do the right thing and
>   convert

one last thing to consider/keep in mind:

[use of Sys::SigAction::timeout_call unsafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792444/use-of-syssigactiontimeout-call-unsafe)